# Is there a way to prohibit using a class as spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way (any annotation of base class) using which i can mark a class such that spring throws an error on context initialization? Basically i have a class which is not thread safe by design and i do not want anybody to use it with spring as singleton bean. I know it can be used as prototype bean but can i prohibit, it being used as spring bean altogether?

Comment: There's no built-in way that I'm aware of, but you might be able to hack something together. However, you'd be tying your class Spring as a dependency just so it can't be Spring managed.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider `@PostConstruct` does not require a dependency on Spring

Comment: True... Though the question asked specifically about Spring. `@PostConstruct `  would allow no dependency injection at all, which may be what's desired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make its post-initialisation method throw.

Either implement [`InitializingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)

```
public final void afterPropertiesSet() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Or use a [JEE annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

```
@PostConstruct
public final void forbidDependencyInjection() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your custom [BeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html)

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException { 
   Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean);
   if (targetClass == MyProhibited.class)) {
       ....
       return null;
    }

   return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define an aspect around or before all or some methods of that class that threw an exception in case of being invoked. That wouldn't require modifying the class.